# How to reach interface alias bond0

Tags: debian, networking, bonding

I'am setting up an interface alias with my bond0 network. 
Why am I not able to ping/reach the second ip address, in this case 192.168.30.84?
However I can ping the address from another server.

```
~# ifconfig bond0
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:1e:eb:68  
          inet addr:192.168.30.82  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92b1:1cff:fe1e:eb68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6924946 errors:0 dropped:2670931 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82824 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:921251441 (878.5 MiB)  TX bytes:6424239 (6.1 MiB)

bond0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:1e:eb:68  
          inet addr:192.168.30.84  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 16436 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:b1:1c:1e:eb:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:b1:1c:1e:eb:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 90:b1:1c:1e:eb:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.30.82/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global bond0
    inet 192.168.30.84/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global secondary bond0:0
    inet6 fe80::92b1:1cff:fe1e:eb68/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto bond0                                                                                                       

iface bond0 inet static                                                         
    address 192.168.30.82                                                       
    netmask 255.255.0.0                                                         
    gateway 192.168.0.1                                                         
    slaves eth0 eth1                                                            
    bond_mode active-backup                                                     
    bond_miimon 100                                                             
    bond_downdelay 200                                                          
    bond_updelay 200                                                            

auto bond0:0                                                                    
iface bond0:0 inet static                                                       
    address 192.168.30.84                                                       
    netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: I prefer `ip` syntax, i.e. add a line to the bond0 stanza: `up ip add addr 192.168.30.84/16 dev bond0`. Check it with `ip addr show` or `ip a` for short.